# MKMapView Observer

Tags: ios, xcode

I am adding an observer to 60 MKMapViews in this way:

```
[mapView2.userLocation addObserver:self
                                    forKeyPath:@"location"
                                       options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)

                                       context:NULL];
```

...

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath  
                 ofObject:(id)object  
                   change:(NSDictionary *)change  
                  context:(void *)context {  

if ([self.mapView isUserLocationVisible]) { 

    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ { 
        // Code to run once

    MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
    mapRegion.center = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
    mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;

    [mapView setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
    // and of course you can use here old and new location values

        });


    for (MKMapView *map in mapViewArray)
    {

        if ([map isUserLocationVisible]) { 


                // Code to run once

                MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion; 

            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [[map.annotations lastObject] coordinate];


                mapRegion.center = coordinate;
                mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
                mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;

                [map setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
                // and of course you can use here old and new location values




        }
}}
}
```

Since then I see a lot of memory taken up. Does this take up a lot of memory?
How can I remove the observer in the viewDidUnload?

Comment: do you really use 60 MKMapViews? I think they are eating memory, not observers.

Comment: you can use MKMapView delegate instead of observers -> - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation

Comment: It answer for question how to remove observer. Is it neccessary to use a lot of map views?

Comment: Are all maps placed on table view or uiview?

Comment: Placed in a UIScrollView

Comment: you can try put it on table view, cell reusing will help save a memory